# Create an excel with two sheets with openxlsx in R

Tags: r, openxlsx

Hello I am trying to create an xlsx with two sheets with openxlsx and it does not work for me, could you help me, it has to be with this library, not another one.

```
write.xlsx(dataOrd1,file="./Red_Total5.xlsx",sheetName="4G_Total",asTable = TRUE ,append = TRUE)
write.xlsx(dataOrd3,file="./Red_Total5.xlsx",sheetName="5G_Total",asTable = TRUE ,append = TRUE)
```

in the end I only create the excel Red_total but only with the sheet 5G_Total

Comment: did you consider the addWorksheet Add a worksheet to a workbook section of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/openxlsx.pdf ?  would that approach work for you?  the example works with a number of sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a list of data frames in `write.xlsx`:

```r
write.xlsx(
  list(`4G_Total` = dataOrd1, `5G_Total` = dataOrd3),
  "./Red_Total5.xlsx"
  )
```